# Remove Windows, install ubuntu while keeping backup partition (D:) + confusing partitioning

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows, backup

I have a 480GB SSD split into two partitions, denoted as (C:) and (D:).

My objective is to eliminate Windows from the (C:) partition.

Subsequently, I aim to install Ubuntu in its place, ensuring all data remains intact on the (D:) backup partition.

How can I achieve this?

Consider /dev/sda3 is (C:)

Consider /dev/sda5 is (D:)

[image]

Comment: You can use the *Something else* or *Manual Partitioning* option to tell the installer exactly what you want. You didn't provide Ubuntu product or release details; as some releases (eg. Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop) provide different ISO choices that use different installers, meaning how the detail is presented on screen varies on your installer (Ubuntu offers 3 installers; 1 for Server, 2 for Desktop, with flavors also using others).  If your system is uEFI you'll need to have an ESP, and you can just use your old *C* as the "/" partition if you wish.

Comment: If it was me doing the install, I'd just **ignore** the sda5/D partition as for install, and add an entry for that **after** your system is installed (ie. add it to your *file-system table* for example). My guess is your picture is showing a `ubiquity` installer picture, but sorry I see installers so often I can't always reliably pick one from another (*thus assume nothing unless specifically told and you didn't mention product/release*)

Comment: Just format sda3. Don't create a new partition table. Make sure nothing changes or is selected for sda5

Comment: Not a good idea to leave d: as NTFS. You can only repair it from Windows. It will eventually need chkdsk and defrag from Windows. And good backups required, before doing anything major like this. If only using Ubuntu use Linux formats like ext4. If you do leave it make sure Windows fast startup is off, so hibernation flag not set. We see many where a NTFS is left hibernated & then the Linux NTFS driver cannot mount read/write. https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation